# django-ckeditor, failed to load mathjax

Tags: django, mathjax, django-ckeditor

I failed to load mathjax within django-ckeditor

This post contains my virtualenv config, CKEDITOR_CONFIGS, printscreen, and an element from the Source page.

**virtualenv**

```
>pip freeze
Django==1.10.2
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-ckeditor==5.1.1
django-compressor==2.1
django-debug-toolbar==1.6
Pillow==3.4.2
psycopg2==2.6.2
rcssmin==1.0.6
rjsmin==1.0.12
sqlparse==0.2.1
```

**CKEDITOR_CONFIGS**

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moono',
        # 'skin': 'office2013',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            {'name': 'document', 'items': [
                'Subscript', 'Superscript', ]},
            {'name': 'source', 'items': [
                'Source', ]},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        'height': 200,
        'width': 600,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(['mathjax', ]),
    },
}
```

According to [problems with mathjax #256](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/issues/256), I've changed ckeditor-init.js. I also tried various combinations, including `{'name': 'math', 'items': ['mathjax', ]},` and `{'name': 'math', 'items': ['Matjax', ]}` in 'toolbar_Custom' list.

**Printscreen**

[image]

**Source**
As you can see the panel contains all config I setup in config but mathjax. However, the page source contains the "toolbar_Basic", "toolbar_Full" & "toolbar_Custom". I'm not sure if Basic and Full should be present, according to my config.

```
< div class = "django-ckeditor-widget"
data - field - id = "id_false_answer_text"
style = "display: inline-block;" >
  < textarea cols = "40"
id = "id_false_answer_text"
name = "false_answer_text"
rows = "10"
required data - processed = "0"
data - config = '{"toolbar_Basic": [["Source", "-", "Bold", "Italic"]], "toolbar_Full": [["Styles", "Format", "Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strike", "SpellChecker", "Undo", "Redo"], ["Link", "Unlink", "Anchor"], ["Image", "Flash", "Table", "HorizontalRule"], ["TextColor", "BGColor"], ["Smiley", "SpecialChar"], ["Source"]], "filebrowserUploadUrl": "/ckeditor/upload/", "skin": "moono", "filebrowserWindowWidth": 940, "filebrowserWindowHeight": 725, "width": 600, "height": 200, "filebrowserBrowseUrl": "/ckeditor/browse/", "language": "en-us", "toolbar": "Custom", "toolbar_Custom": [{"items": ["Subscript", "Superscript"], "name": "document"}, {"items": ["Source"], "name": "source"}, {"items": ["mathjax"], "name": "mathjax"}]}'
data - external - plugin - resources = '[]'
data - id = "id_false_answer_text"
data - type = "ckeditortype" > & lt;
p & gt;
fa4 q1 & lt;
/p&gt;</textarea >
</div>
```

**Another config**
All-plugin config (according to a post from web) also shows no mathjax icon. Both with and without change of 'ckeditor-init.js

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'none',
        'height': 200,
        'width': 600,
     },
}
```

[image: screenshot022]

So as example config from the README.rst

**Static files**
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
[image: screenshot023]

**The quesiton is:**

If it is an issue, how can I quickfix it?
If it is related to configuration inexperience, could you please direct me to the config examples/the right config for mathjax?

The printscreens come from Django admin, I use RichTextUploadingField in these models.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 4):

This was a misconfiguration issue, no problems with Django-CKEditor. The key part of config for mathjax as follows.

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moono',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            {'name': 'math', 'items': ['Mathjax', ]},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(['mathjax',]),
    },
}
```

Both **toolbar** and **extraPligins** should be present in config for mathjax to appear and work.